# Symfony FOSOAuthServerBundle ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, symfony, security, oauth

I'm trying to make an OAuth server with symfony and the FOSOAuthServerBundle bundle. I'm following [this tutorial](https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/07/19/oauth2-explained-part-3-using-oauth2-bare-hands/%22this%20tutorial%22) and I'm on the "Authorization Code" part (Maybe you should check the parts before). When I open the URL `PROVIDER_HOST/oauth/v2/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=CLIENT_HOST` in Browser, I'm getting an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. Here is the output from my log file:

> [2017-10-11 09:50:58] request.INFO: Matched route
>   "fos_oauth_server_authorize".
>   {"route":"fos_oauth_server_authorize","route_parameters":{"_controller":"FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\AuthorizeController::authorizeAction","_route":"fos_oauth_server_authorize"},"request_uri":"http://example.de/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/auth?client_id=3_4ip472z6jf6scgoog0kssg8so0sosg0ok400w80ccog0s88gs0&redirect_uri=test.local&response_type=code","method":"GET"}
>
> [] [2017-10-11 09:50:58] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was
>   thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point.
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code:
>   0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at
>   .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:53)"}
>
> [] [2017-10-11 09:50:58] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry
>   point. [] []
>
> [2017-10-11 09:51:00] request.INFO: Matched route
>   "acme_oauth_server_auth_login".
>   {"route":"acme_oauth_server_auth_login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"SsoBundle\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction","_route":"acme_oauth_server_auth_login"},"request_uri":"http://example.de/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/auth_login","method":"GET"}
>
> [] [2017-10-11 09:51:00] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was
>   thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point.
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code:
>   0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at
>   .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:53)"}
>
> [] [2017-10-11 09:51:00] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry
>   point. [] []

The last 3 logs repeats now... I have tried to debug it with `echo "test"; die();` within the AuthorizeController and the SecurityController, however that was not even working.

Here is my SecurityController:

```
namespace SsoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {

        $session = $request->getSession();

        if ($request->attributes->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $session->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = '';
        }

        if ($error) {
            $error = $error->getMessage(
            ); // WARNING! Symfony source code identifies this line as a potential security threat.
        }

        $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME);

        return $this->render(
            'SsoBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
            array(
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error' => $error,
            )
        );
    }

    public function loginCheckAction(Request $request)
    {

    }
}
```

And here my security.yml:

```
security:

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        user_provider:
            id: platform.user.provider

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
            security:   false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                provider: user_provider
                check_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login_check
                login_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

        oauth_authorize:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
            form_login:
                provider: user_provider
                check_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login_check
                login_path: /oauth/v2/auth_login
            anonymous: true

        api:
            pattern:    ^/api/.*
            fos_oauth:  true
            stateless:  true

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~

    encoders:
        SsoBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] }
        - { path: ^/demo/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I had to change some things from the tutorial, because it was not working everything. But now I have no Idea what I can do this time.

Anyone know what could be the problem? If you need more code, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony will pick the first firewall that is appropriate for url. In your case multiple firewalls will match with `^/oauth/v2/auth`. Both `secured_area` and `oauth_authorize`. Since `secured_area` looks like a fallback that catches all urls not covered by other firewalls you might want to move it to the end of the file, so it's checked last.

My guess is that `secured_area` (which does not allow anonymous access?) is called and then will redirect to ask for authentication landing at the same firewall and thus looping.